# A question on elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Is it possible to express $$(a-b)^3+(b-c)^3+(c-a)^3$$ as a combination of elementary symmetric functions $a+b+c, ab+ac+bc$, and $abc$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you swap $a,b$, that turns into $(b-a)^3+(a-c)^3+(c-b)^3=-(a-b)^3-(b-c)^3-(c-a)^3$, so it's not symmetric.

Comment: Beat you by 2 seconds!

Comment: @Mario @ John Thank you very much. Is it possible to make it symmetric?

Comment: If the power is even, $(a-b)^{2k}+(b-c)^{2k}+(c-a)^{2k}$, is it possible?

Comment: @littlestar Yes, by the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), but I don't know of any simple characterization of the expression for all $k$.

Comment: For $k=1$, $p_1=2s_1^2-6s_2$; for $k=2$, $p_2=2s_1^4-12s_1^2s_2+18s_2^2$, where $p_k=(a-b)^{2k}+(b-c)^{2k}+(c-a)^{2k}$ and $s_1=a+b+c,s_2=ab+ac+bc,s_3=abc$.

Answer (score 0):

No, because if you swap $b$ with $c$ (say), you change the sign.